# Check computation of limit distribution of $\max\{X_1, \ldots , X_n\}/\sqrt n$ for i.i.d. $(X_i)$ with PDF $2/x^3$ on $x>1$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> $X_1$, $X_2$, . . . are iid random variables having pdf $$f_X(x)
>  =\frac{2}{x^3}I_{(1,\infty)}(x)$$  Let $$T_n= \frac{\text{max}{\{X_1, . . . , X_n}\}}{\sqrt{n}}$$
>   (a) Consider the sequence $T_1$, $T_2$, . . . and give the pmf or pdf of the limiting distribution.

I first note that the cdf of $X$ is given by

$$ F_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
1-\frac{1}{x^2} & x \gt 1 \\
0 & x\leq 1 \\
\end{cases} $$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
F_{T_n}(t)
&=\mathsf P(T_n\leq t)\\\\
&=\mathsf P\left(\frac{\text{max}{\{X_1,...,X_n}\}}{\sqrt{n}}\leq t\right)\\\\
&=\mathsf P\left(\text{max}{\{X_1,...,X_n}\}\leq \sqrt{n}\cdot t\right)\\\\
&=\mathsf P\left(X_1\leq \sqrt{n}\cdot t,...,X_n\leq\sqrt{n}\cdot t\right)\\\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathsf P\left(X_i \leq \sqrt{n}\cdot t\right)\\\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n}\cdot t)^2}\right)^n
\end{align*}$$

Altogether, we have

$$ F_{T_n}(t)=  
\begin{cases} 
\left(1-\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n}\cdot t)^2}\right)^n & t \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\
0 & x\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\
\end{cases} $$

Using the property that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e^x$$

we get

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F_{T_n}(t)=  
\begin{cases} 
e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}} & t \gt 0 \\
0 & t \lt 0 \\
\end{cases} $$

Then

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\right)=\frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}}{t^3}$$

Finally, we get

$$f_T(t)=\frac{2e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}}{t^3}I_{(0,\infty)}(t)$$

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: It is fine. Just note that $F_{T_{n}}(0)=0$ but this is not required to find the density.